# How can I use trigonometric functions in C in degrees?

Tags: c, function, mapping, trigonometry

I need to use trigonometric functions in my C program, but I have a problem because I do not control all of the code of my program,  for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "function.h"
double f(double x); 
int main()
{
    double pointx,pointy;
    scanf("%lf",&pointx);
    pointy = f(pointx);
    /* and then I will use pointy in some further places, but
       somebody else provides me with "function.h" and the body of
       the function f, so I don't know what it does */
    return 0;
}
```

When I put 10 instead of x I get a false result because sin  function accepts radian, and this function is going to be given by  the user. I mean it is changeable ,and it can be containing both linear part  ,and trigonmetric part.When I insert a point in that fuction I get false results,I want to emphesize that there is no certain function it can be any function , so I cannot write something that turns degree x to radian x simply.

Comment: How do you write `f(x) = ...` in C?  It is not clear what you want. If you need a parser, the parser could handle degree/radiant for you.

Comment: I wrote it as pseudo code

Comment: The trig functions work with radians, there is no setting for degrees.

Comment: Multiplying by pi/180 is that hard?

Comment: @alp : That last comment makes no sense.

Comment: Your example is not valid C code - it would make mores sense to use an example that is C.

Comment: Program gets the function from the user ,so I do not what the function is.Therefore,I dont turn degrees to radian

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "Program gets the function from the user". Is the function a string that is read from stdin and do you parse this string? Or what exactly does your program do?

Comment: At some point you need to look at what the user gave you and figure out they're using sine, for example.  When you see that, multiply the operand by pi/180.

Comment: You are describing a classic user interface problem.  The user interface must be clear in specifying to the user what units shall be entered in.  Otherwise, there is no way to distinguish one integer value from an another in terms of what they represent.

Comment: @alp : That still makes no sense.  C is a compiled language, the user cannot decide what C functon to call.  If you are writing an expression evaluator, it is your choice what the trig units are - if you want to interpret as degrees, do so - the interpreter must deal with it.  Sounds like an X-Y problem to me.

Comment: Ok, now you have changed the question, it is only a little clearer but malkes little more sense.  If you are linking a provided function, it is a given that that function must conform to specific _a priori_ constraints regarding the semantics of its arguments.  It cannot be decided by the caller at runtime whether the argument is to be interpreted as degrees or radians - it must either be radians or degrees as specified by the function implementation.

Comment: Surely you really want to know is  _"How can I determine whether a trig function takes degrees or radians?"_  The answer is by the documentation of the function.  The standard C library trig functions are always in radians - so you always know.

Comment: Needs more work to be clear what you are asking.  Deleting my answer because it no longer appears to be what you are asking.

Comment: Your changes - even with your original code rather then my trimmed down example now makes no sense because the body refers ot the sin() function which is not mentioned at all in the example,  For any function f(x) it must be defined what x means (its semantics)  it cannot be arbitrarily degrees of radians depending of the direction of teh wind - it is necessarily documented by the implementer - if you want to use degrees and the implementation required radians - do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code sample correctly, your program calls an external function named `f`, which someone else has written and provided to you.  That person should also have told you what input it expects, and what it returns: for instance, that it takes an angle in radians and returns another angle in radians.  We call that the *interface specification* of `f`.  You don't have to know exactly what `f` does internally to know what its interface specification is.

Your program must match the interface specification; for instance, if you want to read the angle as user input in degrees, you must convert the value to radians before calling `f`.  But `f` must also match the specification; for instance, if it is documented to take input in radians but it actually takes input in degrees, then `f` has a bug, and it is the other programmer's responsibility to fix it.  And the specification must be concrete enough that everyone involved knows what they should do.  "`f` could be any function" is not enough.  If that's all you have, you need to talk to the person who's writing `f` and make the specification more, er, specific.